# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I'm new on `ruby` (this is maybe my first program) and I'm trying to make a script that install pacman (packages manager) optional dependences.
I've write this code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
packs=""
exit if ARGV.count==0
ARGV.each do |arg|

    out=%x(LANG="C" pacman -Si #{arg})
    next if out.empty?

    packs+="{arg} "

    lines=out.split "\n"
    first=(lines[11].split ":")[1].strip 

    next if first == "None"

    packs+="#{first} "

    i=12
    while lines[i][0]==" " do

        packs+=(lines[i].split ":")[0].strip + " "
        i++

    end
end
exec ("pacman -S #{packs}")
```

But when I try to run the script i get these errors:

```
    ./pacman-odep:24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
    ./pacman-odep:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:
If you want you can test the script with the `out` variable equals to this text:

```
Repository     : extra
Name           : gimp
Version        : 2.8.14-2
Description    : GNU Image Manipulation Program
Architecture   : x86_64
URL            : http://www.gimp.org/
Licenses       : GPL  LGPL
Groups         : None
Provides       : None
Depends On     : pygtk  lcms  libxpm  libwmf  libxmu  librsvg  libmng  dbus-glib  libexif
                 gegl  jasper  desktop-file-utils  hicolor-icon-theme  babl  openexr
Optional Deps  : gutenprint: for sophisticated printing only as gimp has built-in cups print
                 support
                 webkitgtk2: for the help browser
                 poppler-glib: for pdf support
                 alsa-lib: for MIDI event controller module
                 curl: for URI support
                 ghostscript: for postscript support
Conflicts With : gimp-devel
Replaces       : None
Download Size  :  11.83 MiB
Installed Size :  65.23 MiB
Packager       : Tobias Powalowski <tpowa@archlinux.org>
Build Date     : Fri May 8 17:48:18 2015
Validated By   : MD5 Sum  SHA256 Sum  Signature
```

Comment: Two of those errors relate to the unmatched double-quote on the last line.

Comment: Don't edit the question to change the sense of it. Editing out your errors renders the question and any existing answers meaningless. I have rolled back your changes.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Might pay to roll back the earlier changes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is

```
exec ("pacman -S {packs})
```

It's missing a speech mark, should be:

```
exec ("pacman -S #{packs}")
```

The second problem is the use of `i++`. Replace with `i+=1`.

Comment: yes, I've corrected the first post now there are 2 errors

Comment: Two suggestions. You need a # before packs: `exec ("pacman -S #{packs}")`. Also replace the line `out=%x(LANG="C" pacman -Si #{arg})` with `out="ruby"` just to test.

Comment: thanks I've corrected but there are still those two errors also with the test `out="ruby"`

Comment: Ah, I've got it. You can't use `i++`. You must use `i+=1`.

Comment: No problem - glad it helped. Had me stumped for a bit - please remember to mark the question as answered.